# Can we specify which algorithm to use (e.g., decision tree, SVM, ensemble, NNs) in Vowpal Wabbit? Or, does Automl select the algorithm itself?

Tags: machine-learning, automl, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to read the [documentation](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Algorithm-details) of Vowpal Wabbit and it doesn't specify how to select specific learning algorithms (Not loss) like SVM,NN, Decision trees, etc. How does one select a specific learning algorithm?

Or does it select the algorithm itself depending on problem type (regression/classification like an automl type or low-code ML library?

There are some blogs showing to use Neural networks with `-nn` command but that isn't part of documentation--is this because it doesn't focus on specific algorithm, as noted above? If so, What is Vowpal Wabbit in essence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vowpal Wabbit is based on online learning (SGD-like updates, but there is also `--bfgs` if you really need batch optimization) and (machine learning) [reductions](https://vowpalwabbit.org/features.html). See some of the [tutorials](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials.html) or [papers](https://vowpalwabbit.org/research.html) to understand the idea of reductions. Many VW papers are also about Contextual Bandit, which is implemented as a reduction to a cost-sensitive one-against-all (OAA) classification (which is further reduced to regression). See a simple [intro into reductions](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/machine-learning-reductions-mother-algorithms-part-i-introduction-67c1a69a4b4e) or a simple [example how binary classification is reduced into regression](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/binary.cc).

As far as I know, VowpalWabbit does not support Decision trees nor ensembles, but see [`--boosting`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02651) and [`--bootstrap`](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#learning-algorithm--reduction-options). It does not support SVM, but see `--loss_function hinge` (hinge loss is one of the two key concepts of SVM) and [`--ksvm`](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/ksvm.pdf). It does not support NN, but `--nn` (and [related options](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#neural-network-options)) provides a very limited support simulating a single hidden layer (feed-forward with tanh activation function), which can be added into the reduction stack.

Comment: @amrtin, thank you for the answer. Can you please add any paper/tutorial specific to reduction? its seems like all are about "contextual bandit" and not about "reduction". There is some description about reduction under "Anatomy of a reduction stack" but it is too abstract

Comment: Yes, many VW papers are also about CB, which is also implemented as a reduction to a cost-sensitive OAA. See a [simple intro](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/machine-learning-reductions-mother-algorithms-part-i-introduction-67c1a69a4b4e) or a [simple example](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/binary.cc).

Comment: Thankyou, I have accepted the answer, feel free to add this comment in the answer.